# Uploading pdf file with php to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I get no errors, the connection is working but my database is not receiving any data. I've been following a tutorial and its not my own code, however I can't see where I have made a mistake.

I have created a table called files which corresponds with the parameters used in the code below.

The code is located in a file called uploader.php:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['uploader']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)

 {
 echo "working";
 $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');

$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));

$content = addslashes($content);

fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())

{

$fileName = addslashes($fileName);

}

mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

mysql_select_db("globe_bank");

$query = "INSERT INTO files (name, size, type, content ) ".

"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

echo "
File $fileName uploaded
";

}

?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="246">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />

<input id="userfile" type="file" name="userfile" /></td>
<td width="80"><input id="uploader" type="submit" name="uploader" value=" Uploader " /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: And btw: your code is wide open to sql injection attacks and you are using a  completely outdated, deprecated and actually discontinued sql adapter extension.

Comment: obviously a 1990's tutorial; time to step into the 21st century

Comment: *"I get no errors"* - That's because you didn't check for them, you'd be surprised what you'll find when you do.

Comment: Yes, it obvious this code is not good, but you've got to start somewhere. So the connection is working, how do you know that? Is there anything in `$content`? What does the actual query look like? Do you see the message "File .... uploaded"? These are basic debugging steps you should do, and know the answers to.